# How to make Dice Search API exclude a particular profile during Search

Tags: search, profile, dice, candidate

I am Currently using the dice API,
Docs for API:https://dice-talent-public.api-docs.io/2.0/profile-api/profiles-search.

In this API the profile search and profile view is the thing I am using the most.

NOTE:

- PROFILE VIEW API: RETURNS ONE CANDIDATE
- PROFILE SEARCH API: RETURNS MULTIPLE CANDIDATE

Let me the explain the process

- First I run the Profile Search API and get the result based on the filters.
- Once I found the candidate I prefer, I use the Profile view API and pass the candidates ID to view the entire profile of the candidate.
- But when I search again using the Profile Search API I don't want that particular profile returned by the profile view API.
- Is there a way to exclude a profile while searching for it without affecting the page count or page Size.

I tried searching for any parameters that does that but there wasn't anything!